# How to force gradle to use/share ~/.m2/repository with Maven system wide?

Tags: gradle

By default Gradle uses `~/.gradle/cache` as cache for Maven artifacts.

I also use Maven and set proxy and repository URLs in `~/.m2/settings.xml` and don't want duplicate this settings to Gradle.

Official solution is to add:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()  # <== THIS
}
```

to your `build.gradle`. This requires changing project build script and not acceptable.

Is it possible to set this setting system wide or outside of project (without editing project own files)?

Comment: You touch on many points (cache, settings.xml, mavenLocal()), which makes it hard to figure out what exactly the question is. I don't understand the last sentence. Are you aware of init scripts ( `~/.gradle/init.gradle`, see [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I routinely want mavenLocal for the buildscript, need it multi-module projects and sometimes need to disable it, so this is what I use in ~/.gradle/init.d/mavenLocal.gradle:

```
allprojects { project ->
    buildscript {
        if( !project.hasProperty('skipMavenLocal') ) {
            repositories {
                println "Adding buildscript mavenLocal()"
                mavenLocal()
            }
            configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'hours'
            }
        }
    }

    if( !project.hasProperty('skipMavenLocal') ) {
        repositories {
            println "Adding mavenLocal()"
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 I look exactly for such solution.